# Modify list with python by index[0] value

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have browsed similar threads a lot, but maybe due my lack of knowledge in python, I haven't found a working solution in my problem.

This is part of the code:

```
for line in splitline:
    if("Fam" in line):
        if("NK" in line or "V" in line):
            normaali = line.split()
            normaalilista.append(normaali)
            both.append(normaali)
        if("TK" in line):
            tumor = line.split()
            tuumorilista.append(tumor)
            both.append(tumor)
```

the output of "both" looks like this atm:

```
['Fam_c828_1', '12-0799NK', '100']
['Fam_c828_1', '12-0800TK', '100']
['Fam_s56_1', '12-0801TK', '100']
['Fam_s134_1', '12-0802NK', '100']
['Fam_s146_1', '12-0803TK', '100']
```

I would like to reserve lines / cells with the same index[0] value. Like in this case:

```
['Fam_c828_1', '12-0799NK', '100']
['Fam_c828_1', '12-0800TK', '100']
```

and the rest would be removed to another list.

Thanks in advance

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16349097/python-nested-list-modification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> groups = groupby(both, lambda x: x[0]) # Group `both` by the zeroth index of its members
>>> group = next(groups) # Get the first group in groups
>>> group
('Fam_c828_1', <itertools._grouper object at 0x10f065d10>)
>>> list(group[1]) # Cast the group iterable into a list for display purposes
[['Fam_c828_1', '12-0799NK', '100'], ['Fam_c828_1', '12-0800TK', '100']]
```

Comment: This works beautifully. It currently prints out first group of matches. How I am able to print out all the possible matches by index[0]. Thanks!

Comment: @jester112358 by iterating through the generator returned by `groupby`. Each iteration returns a tuple of the form `(groupkey, group)`.

Comment: I suck at this, I know but, `for files in groups` I get returned something like this:   `('Fam_c69_1', <itertools._grouper object at 0x16e3fc10>)` which probably refers a group inside of it but I have no skill to access it. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: @jester112358 `itertools._grouper` is an iterable. In some ways like a list, but more like a python *generator*. If you don't understand generators and other lazy iterables, [read this](http://www.shutupandship.com/2012/01/understanding-python-iterables-and.html)

Answer (score 1):

To group lines based on the value of the first space-separated column:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defauldict(list) # index[0] -> line
for line in splitline:
    columns = line.split()
    d[columns[0]].append(columns)
```

Comment: Need to play around with it a bit, but seems to do what I was asking. Thanks!